"operation not permitted" while building my container image
I am new to running podman containers. I am pulling the image from a private registry, so I ran
podman login <registery>

then
podman image build . -t my_image

but I got
STEP 1: FROM <registery>
Getting image source signatures
Copying blob <blob> done  
Copying blob <blob> done  
Copying blob <blob> done  
Copying blob <blob> done  
Copying blob <blob> done  
Copying config <blob> done  
Writing manifest to image destination
Storing signatures
Error: error creating build container: Error committing the finished image: error adding layer with blob "sha256:<blob>": Error processing tar file(exit status 1): lchown /etc/shadow: operation not permitted

I have tried editing subuid and subgid
$ cat /etc/subuid
:100000:65536
$ cat /etc/subgid
:100000:65536
But that didn't fix the issue.
I tried executing that command with sudo
sudo podman image build . -t buildbot_dev_env
[sudo] password for mmaher: 
STEP 1: FROM <registery>
Error: error creating build container: Error initializing source docker://<registery>: unexpected http code: 403 (Forbidden), URL: <registery>

Although I ran
sudo podman login <registery>

with no issues. I actually prefer to run rootless. Help is appreciated.
